# Identifying and differentiating among workers when using Backburner for Beanstalkd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, padrino, beanstalkd

I'm trying to use [Backburner](https://github.com/nesquena/backburner) (a Ruby client for [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)) in my application to create, say, 50 workers all watching the same tube for incoming jobs. The problem is, each of those 50 workers, when performing a job, does some heavy file manipulation, etc., and each of them needs to perform some operations on a **uniquely-named numbered directory. For example, worker 7 needs to work with a directory named dir7.**

Initially I thought I could make a `ThreadsOnFork` worker with 50 threads, and I'd be able to access a number associated with each thread from the worker's perform() method, but I haven't been able to do this yet.

How do I handle this situation using Backburner? Or, if it's not possible with Backburner, using some other Ruby beanstalkd client? I hope I'm getting my question across clearly enough. Thanks.

Comment: If the worker just needs a unique place to work on files, why not just create a new directory when you start up the worker process, based on (for example) a GUID, and then delete it when the worker exits.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I solved the issue some other way. I've added my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, the crude way: wrote a shell script that starts a worker by passing its designated number to it via environment variables. Below is a snippet, if anyone's looking for a similar solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 "$1"); do
    env WORKER_NUM=$i rake QUEUES=queue1 backburner:work > logs/backburner.log 2>&1 &
done
```

The rake task becomes available by adding `require 'backburner/tasks'` to the Rakefile, as explained in [the Backburner documentation](http://nesquena.github.com/backburner/).